# Adding drop shadow to UIView on landscape and portrait mode

Tags: iphone, ipad, screen-orientation, ios-autolayout

I am trying to add a drop shadow to a UIView. Here is my code for adding shadow.

```
func addDropShadow() {
    layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 2)
    layer.shadowRadius = 4

    layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).cgPath
    layer.shouldRasterize = true
    layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
}
```

It works fine if device is in portrait mode, but on landscape mode shadow either gets clipped off

[image: Portrait Image]

When I rotate device back again to landscape shadow path moves out of screen.

[image: Portrait Image]

I thought this might be due to orientation change frame of view also gets updated. So I updated shadow path property in viewDidLayoutSubviews method.
But the behaviour remains the same.

Here is my code

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.dropShadowView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.dropShadowView.bounds).cgPath
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will find it much easier to manage the shadow if you make this a subclass of `UIView` and override `layoutSubviews()`:

```
@IBDesignable
class SimpleShadowedView: UIView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 2)
        layer.shadowRadius = 4

        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).cgPath
        layer.shouldRasterize = true
        layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

    }
}
```

Note also that, by adding the `@IBDesignable` designation you can also see the output during design-time.

Set the Custom Class of your view in Storyboard / Interface builder to `SimpleShadowedView`:

[image]

It will show at runtime:

[image]

[image]

If you select `Editor -> Refresh All Views` (or, `Automatically Refresh Views`), you'll also see it at design-time.

[image]

Comment: worked like a charm thank you so much, but I do not get why it didn't in my approach.